# How can I use Typescript 1.7.2 in VS 2015?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015

I see that Typescript 1.7.2 has been released on GitHub a few days ago.

How can I use this now in VS 2015?

I have the TS extension installed, but it's at 1.6.3.

Comment: If you are interested how to install the version with NPM then it should be: `npm install git://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript.git#ad59202a938d8f8d46d116e6f110c7cfbaff8384`. However, it hangs on my computer for some reason. Nevertheless, you should wait until they release the version oficially. Because it is not at the moment, it's only a tagged commit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lastest [Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RC](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx) comes with TypeScript 1.7 support.

From the release notes:

> **TypeScript**
>
> Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 includes features from the 1.6 and 1.7
>   releases of the TypeScript tools. It brings significant enhancements
>   to TypeScript's type system and enables support for the polymorphic
>   type, intersection types, local type declarations, generic type
>   aliasing, and user-defined type guard functions.
>
> It also completes ES6 support in TypeScript by adding ES6 Generators
>   and ES6 Class expressions, and brings support for new ES7 feature
>   proposals like ES7 Exponentiation operator and ES7 Async functions.
>
> Additionally, React's JSX is now natively supported by the TypeScript
>   compiler and tooling. This release also enables targeting Node v4's
>   native implementations of ES6 features (--target ES6) while using Node
>   native module system (--module commonjs), apart from an enhanced
>   support for node module path resolution.

Comment: tried to install, broke my version of visual studio. reinstalled visual studio from scratch and tried again, same deal. i don't recommend installing this.